# how to keep guake open (visible)

Tags: terminal, display, visible

I have Guake terminal 3.0.5 on ubuntu 18.04. Currently, my guake shows up when I toggle it on (F12) and disappear if I press toggle key again (F12). However, whenever I unfocus on guake such as clicking on an area ouside guake, it also automatically hide the terminal. 
Is there a way to keep it visible even when unfocused?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in Preferences panel.

Click on Main Window tab and disable the checkbox `Hide on lose focus`.

Comment: FYI my version of Guake 3.7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 required a restart for this setting to take effect.